# unable to download an image by url (Error 403)

Tags: c#, webclient, http-status-code-403

There is a [picture](https://lhscanlation.club/images/e8bf71ba342fdc5cce74ac2084fde0a2/139e31ae8d7ae16261e3168e2a5e49e000051.jpeg) I want to download.

But you'll not be able to see this picture, unless you open [this](https://lhscan.net/read-kaguya-sama-wa-kokurasetai-tensai-tachi-no-renai-zunousen-raw-chapter-143.html) first.

When I try to download the image using the code below, i get a `403 Unauthorized`:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Other");
    webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://lhscanlation.club/images/e8bf71ba342fdc5cce74ac2084fde0a2/139e31ae8d7ae16261e3168e2a5e49e000051.jpeg"), "page_.jpeg");
}
```

How do I get rid of 403 error in this situation?

Comment: You need to set the `Referer` header to the second URL. The `User-Agent` header is obsolete as well. Enjoy your Kaguya-sama ;)

Comment: _webClient.Headers.Add("Referer", "https://lhscan.net/....html");_
Like this?

Comment: @TobiasTengler and also how do I set proper `User-agent`?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. You don't need an User-Agent header for this to work.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Looks like it's working! And yes, I'll enjoy my Kaguya-sama ;)

Comment: Thank you @TobiasTengler. Referer worked for me. I explored all the internet to find a workaround but lastly you helped me.